# reference error:html is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript . I wants to run a `html` page `index.html` but could not. how can `html` be not defined. please help. the code here just creates a server and runs a `html` page.

```
  var http=require('http');
      var fs=require('fs');
      fs.readFile('index.html',(err,html)=>
      {if (err) throw err;})
       var server=http.createServer((req,res)=>{`enter code here`
       res.statusCode=200;
       res.setHeader('contentType','text/html');
       res.write(html);
       //res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
       res.end();
      }).listen(8081);

          console.log('server started');
```

Comment: Do you want to serve an html ?

Comment: yeh, it was a typo .corrected it now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('index.html', (err,html) => {
    if (err) { throw err; }
    var server = http.createServer((req,res) => {
        res.statusCode=200;
        res.setHeader('contentType', 'text/html');
        res.write(html);
        res.end();
    }).listen(8081);
    console.log('server started');
});
```

That's why you should always indent, format and read your own code (and maybe consider using linter because it would have told you exactly what was wrong) because I'm not doing your job next time.

Comment: thank-you. I will be more careful next time. please can you also suggest good books and any tutorial for the same. I am a beginner and any help will be appreciated.